# grails asset-pipeline and external JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to migrate from grails 2 to grails 3 so I have to use asset-pipeline plugin to manage my java script files. The problem is that I use couple of external libraries e.g. globalize, ajax-solr.They are quite big and have multiple files which depend one on each other. They also have a lot of dependencies to jquery and use namespaces a lot. So, when I simply copy them into `asset/javascript` I get a lot of exceptions in the console e.g.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AjaxSolr is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ParameterHashStore.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

The first question is where those libaries should be placed? in `asset/javascript` in subfolders? 
Or in `asset/lib` as the documentation suggests? (A common folder that gets added to this set of organization is a "lib" folder. This folder can be useful in organizing third party libraries like jQuery, or Bootstrap. - http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual/). If yes, how to force asset plugin to pick it up from there?

The second how to resolve the issues with dependencies? Should I modify globalize and ajax-solr files with `//= require` directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. I placed globalize in `lib` folder (`grails-app/assets/lib/globalize/`) and created a file `globalize-manifest.js` with all the imports:

```
//= require globalize/lib/globalize
//= require globalize/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.pl-PL.js
...
```

then when I need to use globalize I import it using

```
// require globalize-manifest
```